# Javascript .min Files have invalid characters

Tags: jquery, invalid-characters

I don't know when and how this happens, but very often, when I want to change something in a project I either download the code from the web server via Filezilla or pull it from my git repository the `javascript.min` files have these invalid characters.

I always solved this by re-downloading the files and replacing them. But why is this happening? It really annoys me.

When I open the file on the web server it has these characters too, but the site/functionality is working.

After downloading and testing it locally I get for example: `jQuery is not defined...`

Please see the screenshot below:

[image: Invalid characters]

Comment: What IDE are you using? You should check its encoding options.

Comment: This is Visual Code, but using windows editor i get the same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Filezilla caused the problem. When donwloading a file, lets say jquery.min.js, some strings where transformed to invalid characters.

I set Filezilla **transfer-type to binary** and it worked.